# Do not translate the admin area / How can I set the language of the admin area to English?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am building a multilingual site with 3 languages. Lets say English, Italian and German. English is the default language. Is it possible to leave the admin area untranslatable, even I am currently seeing the actual site in different language other than the default one, just for the administrator of the site, using a module or custom code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the [Administration Language](http://drupal.org/project/admin_language) module. There's only a dev version for the Drupal 7.x branch out currently, but it seems to work well enough (used it in a project myself).

Comment: The only thing bothering me is that it doesn't work for the tabs on the front (edit/translate/delete), you happen to know a solution?

Comment: To dianikol: Glad I could help. @Jurgen All I could come up with is manually overriding the tab titles in the code (in template files, before rendering). The t() function allows you to get them in your preferred language.