# Set to the language of admin pages to english despite the language of front pages?

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do not translate the admin area / How can I set the language of the admin area to English?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19011/do-not-translate-the-admin-area-how-can-i-set-the-language-of-the-admin-area-t)

Just that. I have a multilingual site but I'm very used to see the admin pages in english. Let's say I'm creating a new node in spanish then I see all in spanish language. Is there any way to set the language of admin pages to english despite the language of front pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Administration Language](http://drupal.org/project/admin_language) module lets the administrator see all administration pages in their preferred language.